# Windows api, is written in C or in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, api

I am just curious to know, windows api is written in C or in C++?

Comment: Nearly all of it is more C than C++. C is a lot easier to use from other languages.

Comment: @chris: That is because it is, in fact, written in C :)

Comment: @EdS., Well, the main thing I have on my mind is COM. I don't know whether you want to include that as part of the win32 api, though. There's also GDI+.

Comment: @chris: Yeah, same for the general GDI+ API.  I do not believe that COM is considered part of the Windows API... but that's just really my own assumption now that I think about it.  Also, you *can* in fact use COM from C... it is just a nightmare.

Comment: @EdS., I figured as much. COM in C calls for an extremely hacky/bothersome solution, just like most OOP features.

Answer (score 8):

The Win32 library is written in C.